# R - stacking multiple rows on the same row in dataframe with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

so a simple (maybe not) problem with R.
Let's say I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
x <- data.frame("id" = c("01","01","01","02","02","03","03"),
                "month" = c("jan","feb","mar","feb","mar","jan","mar"),
                "activity" = c(0.23,0.34,0.12,0.45,0.03,0.67,0.98))


id, month, activity
01, jan, 0.23
01, feb, 0.34
01, mar, 0.12
02, feb, 0.45
02, mar, 0.03
03, jan, 0.67
03, mar, 0.98
```

and I want to change it into something who looks like:

```
id, janAct, febAct, marAct
01, 0.23, 0.34, 0.12
02, NA, 0.45, 0.03
03, 0.67, NA, 0.98
```

How can I do it with dplyr?

thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `spread` after `mutate`ing the 'month' column by `paste`ing the 'Act' as suffix.  In order to get the order of the columns as in the expected output, we can convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified in the order of occurrence, otherwise, it will go by alphabetic order

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
   mutate(month = paste0(month, "Act"),
          month = factor(month, levels = unique(month))) %>% 
   spread(month, activity)
#  id janAct febAct marAct
#1 01   0.23   0.34   0.12
#2 02     NA   0.45   0.03
#3 03   0.67     NA   0.98
```

---

Or another option is `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(x), id ~ paste0(month, "Act"), value.var = "activity")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the spread function works beautifully, didn't knew it was doing it so efficiently! :)